# Google+ follow button won't use correct placement

Tags: html, css, google-plus

I am trying to add social media follow buttons to my website. The Facebook and Twitter buttons are placed correctly, but Google+ is not. When I add the widget to my page it is shown, but when I try to place it using css, the placement is off and I am not able to change the height placement no matter if I make "bottom" or "top" assignments. It still is in the same top/bottom place, although it has changed its position horizontally, but vertically, it won't place correctly.

html:

```
<head>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

<footer>
<div class="g-follow" data-annotation="bubble" data-height="20" data-href="//plus.google.com/u/0/111912430241269180209" data-rel="author"></div>
</footer>
```

css:

```
.googlePlusTextForButton{
    position: absolute;
    color: #ffffff;
    top: 30px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Create a https://jsfiddle.net/ with the code to explain what is wrong.

Comment: It's abit hard to do it through jsfiddle as you need a local host or other host to see the Facebook and Google+ buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, I have figured out how to fix it. If anyone has the same problem, I just made a second div around the Google+ button and then used that div to move it with css.

Answer (score 0):

You said that the horizontal placement is correct, or at least that the css is affecting it correctly. Your css is using `margin-left` to move the button horizontally, but you are using `top` to move it vertically. Perhaps `margin-top` will work for vertical placement. You might also need to remove the absolute positioning.